# Docker showing Import Error while running a streamlit app from an image

Tags: docker, streamlit

I have a streamlit app for which I have created an image in docker using the [pymesh/pymesh](https://hub.docker.com/r/pymesh/pymesh) image. 
I am able to successfully build the image. However, when I try to make a container from the image using:

```
docker run -p 8501:8501 meshnetapp:latest
```

I get the following error:

```
2021-10-15 10:50:57.500 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/streamlit/script_runner.py", line 354, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "/app/dockerapp.py", line 20, in <module>
    from preprocess import extract_features
  File "/app/preprocess.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pymesh
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymesh/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .Mesh import Mesh
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymesh/Mesh.py", line 5, in <module>
    import PyMesh
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymesh/lib/PyMesh.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

I tried installing libstdc++ manually using this command:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install libstdc++6
```

But that too doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM pymesh/pymesh:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt ./requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install libstdc++6

EXPOSE 8501

COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT ["streamlit", "run"]

CMD ["dockerapp.py"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your Dockerfile flow, it appears you have an order-of-operations error. You run `pip install` to do the Python flow before installing the library it needs. This seems like it would be the correct order:

```
FROM pymesh/pymesh:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt ./requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install libstdc++6

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8501

COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT ["streamlit", "run"]

CMD ["dockerapp.py"]
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. The reason behind me getting the error is due to some problems with the pymesh and streamlit libraries not being able to work together.
I only get this error when Im importing both of these libraries in the same py file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).